# Magento 2.3: Why do HTML tags manually added in Magento content editor for an CMS page disappear?

Tags: magento2.3

To add an image in the AMP home page, I replaced the `img` tag with `amp-img` as follows.

```
<div style="margin-top: -60px;"><amp-img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="/images/5f83940c725da.jpg" width="320" height="180" layout="responsive"></amp-img></div>
```

Although this line ensures mobile visitors can view our store's homepage with the above image, I don't now see the line of code above on revisiting the Editor button`.

What I see now is `<div style="margin-top: -60px;">` leaving me wondering what causes the loss of previously added tags.

Can any please tell why this happens?

Comment: I'm too out of the Magento to say for sure, bu if I recall Magento still uses TinyMCE as its editor and TinyMCE has a hard coded list of tags it allows.  I'm guessing `amp-img` isn't one of these.

Comment: Do check this, not sure if it will work for you coz you seem to be using new tag https://stackoverflow.com/a/40504498/8593947